# NodeJS Promise, delaying return value

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I am relatively new to NodeJS and JavaScript, but not programming.

I'm looking to return an array of objects after two SSH commands are executed via SSH2 and the output of the commands in the shell has been parsed. I have tried various `Promise`s and examples I have found online, but to no avail. It seems that they just return the empty array without even waiting for the commands to execute. I am looking for any samples or a point in the right direction.

```
return Promise.resolve().then(function() {
  devicesAndScenes = [];
  executeCommand(JSON.stringify(getDeviceJson));
  executeCommand(JSON.stringify(getSceneJson));
}).then(sleep(2000)).then(function() {
  return devicesAndScenes;
});

function sleep(time) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, time)
  })
}
```

Comment: Post the code you have.

Comment: Here is the function thats called 
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(function () {
      devicesAndScenes = [];
      executeCommand(JSON.stringify(getDeviceJson));
      executeCommand(JSON.stringify(getSceneJson));
    }).then(sleep(2000))
    .then(function () {
       return devicesAndScenes;
    });

Comment: and the sleep function 
function sleep(time) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, time)
  })
}

Comment: instead of `sleep(2000)` you want `() => sleep(2000)`

Comment: What library are you using to run the ssh commands?

Comment: Perfect that fixed the issue, and Matt I'm using SSH2 on NPM

Comment: what if the `executeCommand` take `2001ms`? what is executeCommand? perhaps you can promisify it and do things correctly rather than hackishly .. oh and `devicesAndScenes` is either global, or in an outer scope, either way, this is quite nasty code

Comment: let me ask again - **what is `executeCommand`?** because you may think getting the sleep working is "good", but it's prone to failure

Comment: A random sleep period is usually a cover-up for an actual design problem that you have not solved.  The best solution here would not involve any randomly chosen timer wait.

Comment: execute command writes to the SSH console, the command is JSON and I get an immediate response back from the controller, thats parsed out from a JSON response added to the global scoped devicesAndScenes array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the second `.then` (the one with the `sleep()` function) is not returning a promise, therefore it's resolving instantly and not *waiting* the specified `time` before executing the last `.then`

```
return Promise.resolve()
.then(() => {
  /* ... */
})
.then(() => {
  /* your problem was here, if we add a return it should work properly */
  return sleep(2000)
})
.then(() => {
  /* now this wil be executed after the 2000s sleep finishes */
});
```

**Used bracket syntax in the arrow functions to make them a little bit more clear.*